# To find the data from same table using nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table employee(ename,post,salary). Here i need to find all the employees who work in the same post as Arjun(ename).

```
select a.ename(select b.post from employee b where b.ename like 'A%n') from employee a
```

What is wrong with my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
select ename
from employee
where post in (select post from employee where ename = 'Arjun')
```

Comment: i would like to know about the last like could u plz explan me a bit and why is my code giving error....i cannot think thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a subquery that yields a result that you can assign to main query:

```
select a.ename
from employee a
where a.post = (select sub.post
                from employee sub
                where sub.ename like 'A%n')
```

I am not sure why you use the `like` option ... If you want to be sur you only get the *Arjun* name you should write an `=` statement:

```
where sub.ename = 'Arjun'
```

Furthermore the subquery should yield only 1 row; otherwise Oracle will throw you the "`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`" error.